# How to find sum of the functional series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{n^2 + 1}{2^nn!}x^n$$

Please help me to find this sum. I tried to differentiate, integrate, but it returned no result.

Comment: Is it $n^2+1$ or $n^3+1$?

Comment: @Axion004 n^2 + 1

Comment: I've added to the answer to handle the change in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^3+1}{2^n n!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^3}{2^n n!}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n n!}x^n$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n n!}x^n=e^\frac{x}{2}$

Take derivative: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n n!}x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x}{2}}$
 and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n n!}x^n=\frac{x}{2}e^{\frac{x}{2}}$

Repeat above process two more times and get: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^3}{2^n n!}x^n=(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{8})e^\frac{x}{2}$

Finally: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^3+1}{2^n n!}x^n=(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{8})e^\frac{x}{2}$

If the question involved $n^2$ instead of $n^3$ as originally stated, the process will work with one less step.  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2+1}{2^n n!}x^n=(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4})e^\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider

$$\frac{n^3+1}{n!}=\frac{n^2}{(n-1)!}+\frac1{n!}.$$

Then for the first term, decompose $n^2$ as a linear combination

$$a(n-1)(n-2)+b(n-1)+c$$ and see the simplifications.